# About definition of $p$-adic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to understand the definition of $p$-adic integers. I know there are several posts on MSE about that but I still couldn't understand. I am looking at the power series definition:

The $p$-adic integers are the set of formal power series
$$
a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\dotsb +a_np^n+\dotsb
$$
where $p$ is a prime and $a_k\in \{0,1,\dotsc,p-1\}$

> Example: Let $p=2$. Any natural number can be expressed in the aforementioned formal power series form. I don't see any other number other than the natural numbers that can be expressed in the above formal power series form. Is that correct?

Also, as a set it is said that the set of formal power series is bijective with $\mathbb{Z}_p$. May I know what is the explicit bijection?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question.  Are you looking for an example of a $p$-adic number which is not a natural number?  (any rational number is a non-natural $p$-adic number)  Or are you looking for an example of a $p$-adic number which is not rational?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^k=\frac{1}{1-p}$ is a rational number. Perhaps you intended an example of a rational number which is not in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If you want a p-adic number that is not rational, just be sure that the coefficients in your power series (alternatively: the digits in the number's p-adic expansion) do not ever become periodic.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oi...  yes, I had a more lacunary example in mind, by failed in the typing---it is late here, and I am not braining well.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your final question.  The $p$-adic numbers are *equal* to the set of formal power series, not just in bijection with them.  (At least, using the definition of $p$-adic numbers you have mentioned.)

Comment: Well, the $2$-adic integers have in them both square roots of $17$. To see this, you need either Hensel’s Lemma, the fundamental tool of $p$-adic algebra; or you can try $\sqrt{1+a}$ as a series, with $a$ equaling the rather small $2$-adic number $16$. I’ve always liked the latter method, ’cause you can do the computation yourself, and see the $2$-adic expansion developing without any hocus-pocus.

Comment: Similar to the definition of real numbers and formal power series, there are more than one definitions of $p$-adic integers. They are all equivalent to each other. What definition are you using for $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: It is possibly unhelpful to call these "_formal_" power series... After all, they _do_ converge $p$-adically... but, yes, then we should talk about what that means, rather than just looking at "expressions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every rational number with an odd denominator can be expressed as such a power series. For example, $-1$ is the one in which all coefficients equal $1$, and $\frac13$ is the one with $a_0$ and all odd-index coefficients equal to $1$, and all even-index coefficients from $a_2$ on equal to $0$. Writing them in a standard notation for $p$-adics, we have: $$\ldots11111.$$
for $-1$, and $$\ldots01011.$$
for $\frac13$.

You can verify that adding $1$ to the first number produces $0$, and that multiplying the second one by $3$ produces $1$.

If you're worried about those "carry" digits trailing off to the left, remember the $p$-adic absolute value: Out to the left is where the number gets "small" anyway, so we get convergence in cases where the usual absolute value would not work for us.

---

The bijection you ask about is simply that the power series with coefficients $a_0, a_1, a_2$, etc. corresponds to the $p$-adic number whose digits are those coefficients: $$\ldots a_2 a_1 a_0.$$

Comment: This is the answer that I would give, but perhaps OP is not familiar with the infinite-to-the-left $p$-ary notation.

Comment: @Lubin that is possible. Perhaps the OP will leave a comment if this answer, or any part of it, is unclear to them.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm not familiar with the infinite-to-the-left $p$-ary notation. All I know is that you are using $a_k\in\{0,1\}$. Sorry for a basic question.

Comment: @Garfield, no worries! The infinite-to-the-left business is just the same as writing in base $p$, except numbers can extend infinitely to the left, because large powers of $p$ are "small" in the $p$-adic absolute value. Compare: regular decimals can extend infinitely to the right, because large *negative* powers of 10 are "small" in the usual absolute value.

Comment: Just like, in regular binary notation, $1011$ means $1\cdot 2^0 + 1\cdot 2^1 + 0\cdot 2^2 + 1\cdot 2^3$, in $2$-adic notation we can keep going, so the number keeps having more digits to the left, and the power series keeps having more terms.

Comment: I see, so I got a qualitative idea. May I know what number $\cdots 1011.$ corresponds to in this notation? (where everything to the left of the leftmost $1$ is a $0$)

Comment: I am asking because I'm not seeing how $\ldots 0101011.$ is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$ in this notation. Thanks.

Comment: @Garfield the number 1011, with all 0s to the left, is the ordinary binary number eleven.

Comment: @Garfield the case of $1/3$ is kind of hard to see, until you're used to it. If multiplying the number by $3$ isn't convincing, then try using the usual algorithm to write 1/3 as a binary integer. Is it even or odd? Odd, so we write down '$1$' as our rightmost digit, subtract $1$, and divide by $2$ leaving us with $-1/3$. That's odd, so we write another '$1$', subtract $1$, and divide by $2$, giving us $-2/3$. This is even, so we write down a '$0$', and simply divide by $2$. Continuing this process, we obtain the repeating expansion. That's one way.

Comment: @Garfield you can also calculate it this way: $\frac13 = 1 - \frac23 = 1 + \frac{2}{1-4} = 1 + 2(1 + 4 + 4^2 + \cdots) = 1+2+8+32+\cdots$. To check, for example, whether the last four digits are correct, note that $1/3$ shares its last four digits with $11$. They should therefore be congruent, modulo $16$. Indeed, $11 - \frac13 = \frac{32}{3}$, which is a multiple of $16$.